# What is the Rails way to split a view into separate pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Within my show action/view I'm displaying a lot of data that I want to split-up into separate pages (in this case three pages total). I can do this easily by adding a new action and view for each additional page, but is that the "correct" way to do it in Rails?

Comment: http://www.nullislove.com/2007/05/24/pagination-in-rails/

Comment: A new action/view for each additional page would be appropriate if you have three different views of the same resource: You might have, for example, `/my-project`, `/my-project/details` and `/my-project/more-details`.

Comment: Depends on what you actually mean by that; there's no "right" way to separate related data. Tabs via Ajax, links to controller actions, etc. are all possibilities.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give some source code or at least some examples. It's possible it might be better to split it up in a different way than just separate actions.

Comment: might not be exactly what you are looking for, but when i was messing around with it this really helped me http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

> I can do this easily by adding a new action and view for each additional page, but is that the "correct" way to do it in Rails?

I suspect you are unsure about violating REST?

I don't know what data you are displaying, but In the end the clearest and simplest solution for you (code wise) and your users (design wise) should win, if that means adding a new action, so be it. Avoid adding a new controller just for the sake of a new show action.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was concerned with. I went with adding multiple actions and it seems like that was the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a pagination solution? If so, I would suggest either [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). Also, they each have railscast if you need any help getting set up.

Comment: No, not looking for pagination as I want to break-up a single record.